# Explode matching columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using spark to read a csv that contains 2 columns that are arrays, where each cell in the first array matches a cell in the 2nd array, that is:

```
arr1[i] <-> arr2[i]
```

The reading:

```
val table = spark.read.csv("my_data.csv")
```

Example of the data:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| ids     |  avg                |
+---------+---------------------+
|  [11,23]|  [0.368633,0.750615]|
```

I would like to explode the columns in a corresponding matter such that for each row, 'id' and 'avg', will match (and not getting all combinations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [posexplode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#posexplode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) it creates 2 columns one for array values and another for indexes

```
      //first explode and rename position columns
table.select(posexplode($"ids") as Seq("id_pos", "id"), $"avg").
     .select($"id", $"id_pos", posexplode($"avg") as Seq("avg_pos", "avg"))    
      //then keep only rows with the same array position
     .filter($"id_pos" === $"avg_pos")    
      //remove positions from dataframe
     .select($"id", $"avg")
```

Comment: There's a small mistake here - `posexplode` creates two columns where the _first_ is the position, so the naming of the result columns is wrong (which makes the results wrong): should be `as Seq("id_pos", "id")` and `as Seq("avg_pos", "avg")`.

Comment: @TzachZohar Thank you! fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could use a small udf:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    Seq((
      Array(11, 23), 
      Array(0.368633, 0.750615)
    ))).toDF("ids", "avg")

val udfZip = udf((ids: Seq[Int], avg: Seq[Double]) => ids.zip(avg))

val res = df.select(explode(udfZip($"ids", $"avg")).as("pair"))
res.show
// +-------------+
// |        pair|
// +-------------+
// |[11,0.368633]|
// |[23,0.750615]|
// +-------------+

res.printSchema
// root
//  |-- pair: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- _2: double (nullable = false)
```

Or even better UDF:

```
case class Pair(id: Int, avg: Double)
def udfBetterZip = udf[Seq[Pair], Seq[Int], Seq[Double]](
    (ids: Seq[Int], avg: Seq[Double]) => 
        ids.zip(avg).map{
            case (id, avg) => Pair(id, avg)
        }
)

val res2 = df.select(explode(udfBetterZip($"ids", $"avg")).as("pair"))
res2.printSchema
// |-- pair: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
// |    |-- avg: double (nullable = false)
```

Comment: This relies on being able to specify the types for each sub-array, which isn't practical when they are arrays of StructType.